# Object Storage (Softlayer SWIFT) Synchronization Time?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Re. SWIFT cluster synchronization time.

I need to know if there's a deterministic way to check whether a HEAD/GET request for a Dynamic Large Object (DLO) will report accurate Content-Length.

My uploader sends files in XX MB chunks and wraps them with a DLO manifest.  I'm seeing several instances where a client issuing a HEAD or GET request for a DLO object, receives a "short byte count" in the Content-Length field (typically short by 1 or 2 chunks).

Further, some of these instances can persists for several minutes and even HOURS.  In all instances, the Content-Length eventually reports the correct value, so it doesn't look like an uploader bug, it looks like SLOS requires time to synchronize/settle down.

For background info (ignore LightSync), see also: http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/zhai-ennan/titcheu16sync.pdf

So I need to know if my understanding is grounded in reality, and what mechanisms I should be considering to ensure that the SL Object Store reports an accurate Content-Length, to prevent a situation where a client downloads "corrupt" files (files that are missing a chunk).  Is there any SWIFT REST API which provides that guarantee?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The description is working as expected but ‘HOURS’ is definitely too long to be eventually consistent. I recommend to submit a ticket, in order to get further assistance with this behavior. There isn’t a way to deterministically report the new, updated size due to the nature of the eventual consistency.

Perhaps you can try with this header "**X-Newest**", it could be expensive with DLO depending on the number of segments involved, see:

- https://developer.openstack.org/api-ref/object-storage/?expanded=get-object-content-and-metadata-detail#get-object-content-and-metadata

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however the X-Newest flag had no effect in terms of solving our problem.  We've decided to implement our own "DLO" mechanism (still using SLOS chunks) to achieve predictability.  PS: Softlayer support sent me to StackOverflow and asked me to tag the question with "softlayer".

Comment: Attach this forum to the ticket, in order to be escalated